# Преобразить numpy.ndarray в hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, hashlib

Я пытаюсь преобразить numpy.ndarray в hash для дальнейшего сравнения со словарем. Мне необходимо сравнивать изображения друг с другом. Преобразовать необходимо картинку класса 'numpy.ndarray', но получаю ошибку.
ndarray is not C-contiguous

```
m = sha256()
m.update(image_numpy_ndarray) #ошибка
print(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: и вы поискали в гугле вашу ошибку? и он выдал вам кучу результатов? а вы?

Comment: @strawdog ничего не понял. В байты чето не получается перевести.

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз меня только минусуют и не могут дать столь легкий ответ то напишу его я.

```
m = sha256()
m.update(np.array(image_numpy_ndarray, dtype=np.uint8))
print(m.hexdigest())
```

tnh.

Comment: вам не хотят давать столь легкий ответ, потому что он ищется в интернете за 2 минуты.

Comment: @strawdog если бы я знал английский то обращался бы не на "stackoverflow на русском".

Comment: Если бы вы обращались на на stackoverflow на русском, вам бы там сказали то же самое, но не на русском. Надо не лениться и поискать решение самому.

Comment: @stawdog Если бы я знал английский я бы смог нагуглить ответ как вы сказали за 2минуты. У меня ушло много времени. Я не смог нагуглить ответ на русскоязычном пространстве. Как вы понимаете здесь много людей которые не особо знакомы с программированием, и если бы у меня были коллеги они бы подсказали решения, но есть обычные люди которые и обращаются за помощью к таким ресурсам. Прилагают код и искренне не понимаю, не знаю, тупят и не могут найти решения. Но еще больше не можешь понять почему ответ не имеющий отношения к теме имеет больше символов чем ответ который можно было дать. Добра Вам!

Comment: Вы не поняли главного - другие пользователи этого ресурса тоже не знают всего. И им зачастую приходится искать решение подобных вопросов в интернете. То есть, делать за вас вашу работу. Вот вы и превращаете этот ресурс в поисковик.